# Routing in ASP.NET MVC Controllers

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, controller, routes

I have been spending time on ASP.NET MVC 4 for a while now and having worked on other MVC frameworks like the Spring/RoR I, for some reason, dont see ASP.NET MVC doing what the others could do. I am specifically talking about the routing behavior of .Net MVC and it was wondering it is still so rigid. Why did MS chose to do routing in a diff config file, why not just annotate the methods in the controller, is there something wrong with it? Am I missing something?

Comment: central point of configuration can be easier.

Comment: This is what i though before using attribute-routing.You get more control on the urls. You can specify different actions with the same URL, depending on the type of some parts of the url. (eg : if the id is a string, or an integer).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With nuget, you can install Attribute-Routing, which will be automatically included in ASP.Net MVC5

http://attributerouting.net/